# reveal.js losing focus after clicking internal links in FF

Tags: reveal.js

in my presentation I use reveal.js and included internal links to navigate between slides. after clicking the focus is lost. the controls are not working anymore by using the keys. Using the mouse there are no problems. 
in chrome everything works fine, but firefox has this focus problem.

has anybody an idea what i can do?

Comment: Same here, have you reported this bug on github? https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues ... They say it is fixed https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/617 but it does not work for me either.

Comment: Reported here as bug: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/899

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a similar issue in Firefox with browser tab focus.

https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/577

It's probably best to file it as a bug.

One thing I have noticed is, that this only happens when using anchor links

```
<a href="#/4">Link<a/>
```

When you use JavaScript to switch slides everything works fine.

A quick fix could be to add an attribute to your links that specifies the slide number.

```
<a href="#/4" data-slide-num="4">Link<a/>
```

And add this JavaScript to handle the clicks for you.

```
$('[data-slide-num]').click(function(event) {
    var slideNum = $(this).attr('data-slide-num');
    Reveal.slide(slideNum);
    return false;
});
```